# How to Plot the ROC Curve in rStudios from the given values?

Tags: r, roc

Confusion Matrix Values

1. Cut-off       /    TP    /          FP     /      TN     /          FN
2. 0.1                         100         50              500            450
3. 0.2                     150         100             450            400
4. 0.3                     250         150             400            300
5. 0.4                        300      200             350            250
6. 0.5                     350         250             300            200
7. 0.6                     350         300             250            200
8. 0.7                     400         350             200            150
9. 0.8                     400         400             150            150
10. 0.9                     450        450             100            100
11. 1.0                    500         500             50            50

Comment: Note that this is not actually a ROC curve, which should visit every possible threshold, not just 10.  Depending on the context you may want to call it something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only base-R, you could write the following code:

```
## your data
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
Cut_off TP FP TN FN
0.1 100 50 500 450
0.2 150 100 450 400
0.3 250 150 400 300
0.4 300 200 350 250
0.5 350 250 300 200
0.6 350 300 250 200
0.7 400 350 200 150
0.8 400 400 150 150
0.9 450 450 100 100
1.0 500 500 50 50")

## calculate False Positive ratio
df$FPR <- df$FP/(df$FP + df$TN)
## calculte True Positive Ratio
df$TPR <- df$TP/(df$TP + df$FN)

## df is now: 
   Cut_off  TP  FP  TN  FN        FPR       TPR
      0.1 100  50 500 450 0.09090909 0.1818182
      0.2 150 100 450 400 0.18181818 0.2727273
      0.3 250 150 400 300 0.27272727 0.4545455
      0.4 300 200 350 250 0.36363636 0.5454545
      0.5 350 250 300 200 0.45454545 0.6363636
      0.6 350 300 250 200 0.54545455 0.6363636
      0.7 400 350 200 150 0.63636364 0.7272727
      0.8 400 400 150 150 0.72727273 0.7272727
      0.9 450 450 100 100 0.81818182 0.8181818
      1.0 500 500  50  50 0.90909091 0.9090909

## plot the ROC with base plot
plot(df$FPR, df$TPR, type = "b", 
     xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1), 
     main = 'ROC Curve',
     xlab = "False Positive Rate (1 - Specificity)",
     ylab = "True Positive Rate (Sensitivity)",
     col = "blue")
abline(a = 0, b = 1, lty=2, col = "grey") ### pure chance line
```

yielding the following plot:

[image]

if you want to mark the cut-off points with a label you need the following line after the line with `abline(...`

```
text(df$FPR, df$TPR+.05, df$Cut_off, col = "blue", cex = .7)
```

yielding this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can have a ROC plot with `ggplot` and `dplyr`.
First here is your data:

```
df = structure(list(Cutoff = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 
     0.8, 0.9, 1), TP = c(100, 150, 250, 300, 350, 350, 400, 400, 
     450, 500), FP = c(50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 
     500), TN = c(500, 450, 400, 350, 300, 250, 200, 150, 100, 50), 
     FN = c(450, 400, 300, 250, 200, 200, 150, 150, 100, 50)), class = 
     "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))
```

and for ROC, you need False-Positive-rate (FPR) and True-Positive-rate (TPR) which here I calculate with `mutate`:

```
df %>% mutate( FPR = FP / (FP + TN) , TPR = TP / ( TP + FN )) %>%
   ggplot( aes ( x = FPR , y = TPR)) + geom_point(size = 0) + 
   geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 1) + theme_bw() +
   xlab("1 - Specificity") + ylab("Sensitivity") +
   theme(
     plot.title = element_text(size = 20,hjust = 0.5),
     axis.text = element_text(size =10),
     axis.title = element_text(size = 20)
   ) + annotate('segment' , x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 1, alpha = 0.7)
```

And here is the result:
[image]

If you want to have points on the plots you can change the size in `geom_point` and this would be the result:
[image]